# Making a plugin for Ionic from Java

Tags: java, angularjs, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm working with a SDK for developing in Android. I have made some tests and everything seems to be OK in Android (Java). After testing, I want to work with Ionic, and make this Java-SDK usable.

For that, I think I will need to convert or to make a kind of "bridge" betwen Java and Ionic with these posibilities:

- Java --> Cordova
- Java --> Angular

How to do this? I have read about GWT but I think that it is not a good solution because the original SDK is not mine and I can't re-write it.

Thanks.

Comment: I was just wondering has this worked out for you and have you successfully created a working Native Plugin for ionic & using it? (if yes, any advice before I get down this road?)

Comment: @Marko Yes, it finally worked well. It's not so difficult. I started working with the easiest example https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello and after i modified it until reach my goal. There are not many guides but with that example and the official docs https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html i think that you can make it. If you have any doubt, ask here without problems.

Comment: Thats great news then! :) Thanks for the reply, appreciate the helpfulness, hopefully I don't need it but glad I got somewhere to ask if I get stuck ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The easier way:**

Ionic is a framework that lies on top of Angular, which itself lies on top of Cordova's webview or Crosswalk's webview (if you are using that one).

The easiest way for you to bridge the Java code and the JavaScript one is to create a Cordova plugin. Basically you all you have to do (from the Java side) is to extend the `CordovaPlugin` class and override its `exec` method.

You should read the documentation here, because you would need a bit more than just Java code: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html

**The harder way:**

There exists a second option by using `WebView.addJavascriptInterface`, but there you would have handle more things than the first approach.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Instead of making a Cordova plugin, there is any other possibility? Thanks for the reply

Comment: I have updated my answer, to include the `WebView.addJavascriptInterface` .

Comment: I have started to make the plugin and it's the best solution. Thanks, post like an answer.